# Realm Results<T> count returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, count, realm

I'm populating my table view with Realm 'Patient' objects. To get how many rows/sections my tableview should have, i run :

```
class PatientsTableViewController: RealmSearchViewController {

var dataSource : Results<Patient>!
var currentPatient : Patient!
...

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return dataSource.count
}
```

I have this function to set `dataSource` and i call it in `viewDidLoad`

```
func reloadTable()
{
    do
    {
        let realm = try Realm()
        dataSource = realm.objects(Patient)
        tableView?.reloadData()
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

I use the `currentPatient` in another function. However, when i run the app, it crashes and gives me an error of

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and points at

> return dataSource.count

I tried replacing it with `return dataSource!.count` , or creating an object in the `viewDidLoad` (just for testing, i don't want to have any objects that i create) but the error was still there, and i also tried to reset content and settings in the Simulator, but to no good. What should i do ?

Comment: where is `dataSource` set?

Comment: In the file scope, i'll edit my question

Comment: ***set***, not defined. Where you assign anything to it?

Comment: @luk2302 I'm sorry, i don't know why i forgot to mention it. Question edited with the answer regarding your question

Comment: where is that method `reloadTable` called? Probably the tableView requeries its data at the beginning of the view display process - at some point where your `reloadTable` has not been called yet and `dataSource` therefore is still nil.

Comment: @luk2302 I'm calling it in both `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`

Comment: have you including some logging/printing in the method to see either if an error occured or at least logging the `dataSource` value afterwards!?

Comment: No, but i got it working by initialising a `mainDataSource` in my Initial View Controller, adding a prepareForSegue function, and sending it with it. Thank you though! I'll add it as an answer in a few

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by defining and initialising a `mainDataSource` in my Initial View Controller, and passing it through the `prepareForSegue` function to the next view controller's `dataSource` where the app used to crash.